# Unable to find assembly Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, assembly-resolution

I'm developing a web app using NHibernate, and getting the error

```
Unable to find assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'
```

The weird thing is that it's intermittent, and when ti happens it causes the VS 2010 embedded web server to crash. But it doesn't happen on every request, or on any particular request.

I found a few articles online that indicated a few different possible solutions, and have tried them (to include making sure that my /bin folder has a copy, making sure the dll is not blocked, and compling the app for 32-bit).  None of these solutions seem to affect it, and in any case the first couple seem like issues that would be a problem *always*, not intermittently.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible with VS 2008?  Is the problem reproducible with IIS?

Comment: I don't have VS 2008, I'll try it in IIS.  But the issue remains, b/c it's a pretty significant hit to my workflow for developing.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a problem in IIS 7 after about 15 minutes of testing; I get the craches in < 5 in VS 2k10.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten similar errors and found that the real problem is not being reported. If you are getting these while debugging in Visual Studio, it can help to go to Debug > Exceptions and select the "Thrown" checkboxes (I am using VS 2008). For me, this allowed the error to be reported in Visual Studio instead of my web browser, and provided more detailed and accurate error information.

If you do this, realize that some of these exceptions may have been previously handled but now will disrupt your workflow by breaking at those points. If this happens, you can just turn off the exceptions that you don't need to break on.